# Doesn't converge in probability? Doesn't converge almost surely?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, logic

Definition of converge in probability
$$\forall\epsilon,\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=0\iff$$
$$\forall\epsilon,\forall\delta,\exists N,\forall n\geq N,P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)<\delta$$
Is the negation
$$\exists\epsilon,\exists\delta,\exists n_k(\epsilon,\delta),P(|X_{n_k}-X|<\epsilon)>\delta$$
correct?

Definition of almost sure convergence
$$P(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n=X)=1\iff$$
$$P(\forall\epsilon,\exists N,\forall n\geq N,|X_n-X|<\epsilon)=1\iff$$
$$P(\cap_\epsilon\cup_N\cap_{n\geq N}\{|X_n-X|<\epsilon\})=1$$
so the negation is???

Intuitively I think the negation should be 
$$P(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n=X)<1\iff$$
$$P(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n\not=X)>0\iff$$
$$\exists S=\{\omega:\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n\not=X\}\in\mathcal{F},P(S)>0$$
But this doesn't come right from the negation?

Comment: A negation of "$X_n\to X$ almost surely" is $$\exists A\in\mathcal F\ \forall\omega\in A\ \exists\epsilon>0\ \forall k\in\mathbb N\ \exists n\in\mathbb N\ (n\geqslant k\ \wedge\ |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|\geqslant\epsilon)$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes the negations are correct. First one is pretty obvious. Convergence almost surely asserts u get a measurable set M with measure 1 on which X_n(w) converges to X(w) for all w in M. The negation u arrived at is there exists a measurable set S with measure greater than 0 in which for all w Xn(w) doesn't converge to X(w).

Comment: Use Latex man !